# Activity label appears on home screen instead of app name

Tags: android

In AndroidManifest.xml, the application tag has:

android:label="@string/app_name"

and app_name in res/values/strings.xml reads "My App".

But after running or debugging on both the emulator and an attached device, the app icon on the home screen displays the main activity's label instead of the app label. Is this expected behavior, and if not why might it be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is Expected behavior. The app name will be seen in the applications tab in settings. The main screen displays the launcher activity's label.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the app_name property as the label of your application below the launcher icon you can specify the android:label property in the application tag of your android manifest file.

For example:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/myIcon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: That helped. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for this behaviour:

In **manifest**:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity
       android:name=".MainActivity">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In **MainActivity's** **onCreate**:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.activity_name);
```

By doing this, the app name will appear on home screen, and you can still have a different title for your launcher activity.

Answer (score 0):

People see here, I got the same issue and finally resolve it.

Launcher show only the mainActivity because activity label is preferred for Phone Launcher.

So one want show Application labe rather than MainActivity's, he should delete the line:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

delete this:

```
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
```